# Instantiating a class and then pass it to setInterval

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I've a crazy problem. I'm instantiating an object from a class. Then I want to pass a function from this object to the setInterval function. The whole code block is executed with a keyDown event. 
Here's the code:

```
  function doKeyDown(e){
      var instance = new Class(e.keyCode);
      setInterval(instance.functionToBeExecuded(), 200);
  }
```

The strange thing is that it's getting executed once and then starts to loop an error which states (firebug): 
27

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list


[object HTMLAudioElement]
```

For the sake of completeness:

```
Class.prototype.functionToBeExecuded = function(){
 var node = document.createElement("audio");
 //the key is stored in the object (from the Class's constructor)
 node.setAttribute("key", this.variable);
}
```

Does anyone see some fails?

Thanks in advance! =)

P.S.: **This is not a duplicate** cause I'm not facing the function, function() error. If I'm executing it with (instance.functionToBeExecuded, 200) it happens just nothing.

What I've found out so far is that the problem must be in the scope somehow. If I do it like this:

```
  function doKeyDown(e){
      var instance = new Class(e.keyCode);
      setInterval(instance.functionToBeExecuded, 200);
  }

Class.prototype.functionToBeExecuded = function(){
 console.log(this);
 var node = document.createElement("audio");
 //the key is stored in the object (from the Class's constructor)
 node.setAttribute("key", this.variable);
}
```

I'm getting a looping console output with "window". So the function is executed in the window's scope. But why? And how to work around?

Console output:

`Window index.html`

Comment: passing `instance.functionToBeExecuded()` to setInterval causes `eval` execution. Better to use `instance.functionToBeExecuded` as argument

Comment: There's happening nothing if I do it like this. :/

Comment: For this reason I don't post it as answer. I just want to pay your attention to the bad practice you're using

Comment: @zerkms This isn't a duplicate. I'm not facing the function(), function mistake. See the edited question for detailed information.

Comment: @OddDev now it's not anymore. The initial revision of the question was exactly the same problem though.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah I know. But I've overseen this until you've marked it. :) That's why I've made things more clear (hopefully =)).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround would be: wrap it using another function instead of calling method directly

```
function doKeyDown(e){
  var instance = new Class(e.keyCode);
  setInterval(function(){
    instance.functionToBeExecuded()
  }, 200);
}
```

This would give output many of these:

```
Class {functionToBeExecuded: function}
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you!
But why? O.o

Comment: only the function reference passed to the `setInterval`, so it would be executed on `window` context..